# Some problem with dict function

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a list to a dictionary by using the `dict` function.

```
inpu = input.split(",")
dic = dict(inpu)
```

The above code is trying to get a string and `split` it on `','` and afterwards I use the `dict` function to convert the list to a dictionary.

However, I get this error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required

Can anybody help?

Comment: Give us an example of your input, and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: You might want to use `set` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 21):

`dict` expects an iterable of 2-element containers (like a list of tuples). You can't just pass a list of items, it doesn't know what's a key and what's a value.

You are trying to do this:

```
>>> range(10)
<<< [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> dict(range(10))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

`dict` expects a list like this:

```
>>> zip(lowercase[:5], range(5))
<<< 
[('a', 0),
 ('b', 1),
 ('c', 2),
 ('d', 3),
 ('e', 4)]
```

The first element in the tuple becomes the key, the second becomes the value.

```
>>> dict(zip(lowercase[:5], range(5)))
<<< 
{'a': 0,
 'b': 1,
 'c': 2,
 'd': 3,
 'e': 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

As listed on the [Python Data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) Docs. The dict() constructor builds dictionaries directly from lists of key-value pairs stored as tuples.

so the inpu array must be of form ('key', 'value') at each position, for example

```
>>> dict([('sape', 4139), ('guido', 4127), ('jack', 4098)])
{'sape': 4139, 'jack': 4098, 'guido': 4127}
```

your input array is probably greater than 2 in size

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a key-value pair which is why it says length-2 lists are needed to match keys to values. You are splitting the input into a flat list, which is why Python is complaining in this case - it doesn't know what to specify as keys and what to specify as values.